Clang format option for an `if-else if-...-else` with blocks
I have this code, which I would like to keep as it is:
    if (type.empty()) { os << "!EMPTY"; }
    else if (type->as_qubit()) { os << types::qubit_type_name; }
    else { os << *type; }

But clang-format is formatting it as:
    if (type.empty()) {
        os << "!EMPTY";
    } else if (type->as_qubit()) {
        os << types::qubit_type_name;
    } else {        
        os << *type;
    }

This is the .clang-format I'm using:
---
BasedOnStyle: Google
Language: Cpp
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: AllIfsAndElse
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
ColumnLimit: 120
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 0
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
IndentWidth: 4
PointerAlignment: Right
ReflowComments: false
---

Is there a way to tell clang-format to write each if, else if, and if, together with their corresponding blocks, in a single line, whenever they fit?
I'm using clang-format 14.

Not all imaginable code formats can be tuned in clang-format. It's an open source program. If you need some specific format, you can add it in the code.

One kind of hack that could work (only an idea, not tested), is to remove the curly brackets. In my experience such code is more likely to be formated in the same line.

@gerum thanks, but that is a no-opt for me. I use braces even for one sentence blocks as a coding guideline.
